# "My work finishes at 8" or "I finish work at 8"?

Tags: phrase-usage

Which one of the following sentences is correct when I want to say that my workday is over at 8?

> My work finishes at 8.
>
> I finish work at 8.

If both are equally natural, which is more common?

Comment: The second is more natural. There is an implication in the first, that there is no more work, as if you finished a complete job. "My **work finishes**" as opposed to "**I finish** work".

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be no clear preference recognised by English speakers. I guess there are some technical nuances about using "I" as a subject versus "My Work", but for all practical purposes, the two sentences have the same meaning and are completely interchangeable.

And those two are not the only options, either: commonly heard around the office is

> I get off work at 8